# What is the formal plural of the word theorem?

Tags: grammatical-number, latin, greek

The word *theorem* comes from late Latin theōrēma and the Greek θεώρημα . If one wanted a plural form other than *theorems* that reflected its etymology, what would it be?  I understand the standard plural is *theorems* but I would still be interested to know.

Comment: Presumably _theoremata_, though that would be the plural of _theorema_, rather than _theorem_.

Comment: *Theorem* is an English word and gets an English plural. *Theorema* is a Latin word and its plural is presumably *theoremae* — but this is not an English plural because the base word is not an English word.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I accept the point however we do sometimes use plurals that reflect the etymology of a word. For example formulae and formulas are both in use. Not to mention schemas and schemata.

Comment: True, but *formula* is the same in Latin and English (and *schema* the same in Greek and English). *Theorema* is not.

Comment: @AndrewLeach What about llamata ... :)

Comment: There is a group of words that originate in Greek third-declension neuters in _-(η)μα_, and which in Greek have plurals in _-(ῆ)ματα_. Some have been borrowed directly from Greek or Latin as neologisms (stigma, zeugma, anathema) and to the extent that they form plurals, they often retain the Greek plural at least as an option (stigmata, zeugmata). Most, however, come via French and end simply in -m(e) in English (problem, theorem, diaphragm, biome). These invariably take simple English plurals and their connection to the Greek _-(η)μα_ group is obscure and non-transparent.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that stigmata is used as plural for stigma in English. At least nowadays, a stigma is most commonly used in the sense of a social stigma, where stigmata has a religious sense (the marks on the body of Jesus).

Comment: @oerkelens, but the singular of ‘stigmata’ is still ‘stigma’. ‘Stigmata’ is one of the available ways of forming a plural of ‘stigma’ (though only in one sense of the word), whereas it is not an option at all to pluralise ‘problem’ as ‘problemata’, for instance.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The singular of stigmata in the religious form it is commonly used is not stigma. It is an independent concept which doesn't have a separate singular I would argue. Like happiness.

Comment: @Anush, ‘stigmata’ is still a plural. It is not an uncountable noun like ‘happiness’ or ‘furniture’ or ‘paper’. It happens to be almost exclusively spoken of in the plural, but in contexts where a singular is called for, that is ‘stigma’—not ‘a piece of stigmata’ _vel sim_.

Comment: I doubt any modern English reader will normally ever read stigma as the singular of stigmata or vice versa. Yes, in a religious setting, discussing if a single mark is a stigma in the "stigmata"-sense, is is possible. But I have not encountered any headline about social stigmata affecting certain social groups... Purely grammatically the option is there, mostly because both stigma and stigmata are commonly known and even though they normally have a different meaning, they do not "sound" as "strange" as "problemata" would.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Can you find any written evidence of "stigma" in its religious form?  I feel that in modern English the singular and plural are entirely different words now.

Comment: @oerkelens, well, I for one quite naturally read ‘stigmata’ as a specialised plural form of ‘stigma’, just like I consider ‘piles’ (as in haemorrhoids) and ‘the bends’ (decompression sickness) to be specialised plural forms of ‘pile’ and ‘bend’. I would never consider ‘stigma’ and ‘stigmata’ to be unrelated lexemes. And if I had to talk about a single stigmatic mark, I would certainly call it a stigma, not (for example) a ‘stigmaton’ or something like that. (Also, the plural ‘stigmas’ is occasionally used in the religious sense too, showing that the words are associated with each other.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hmm.. How can you ever use "the bends" as a plural?

Comment: @Anush, how would you ever use it as a singular? “If you go up too fast, the bends come and get you!” would be unexceptional, but “If you go up too fast, the bends comes and gets you!” is utterly ungrammatical to my ear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It (strictly in Greek or Latin) would be *theoremata*, just like *schemata*. This is the general declension for several -ma words originating in Greek.

But this seems artificial, and in any case why would you want to use the Greek plural pattern when the English one does the job?

Comment: Thank you. To answer your question directly, only for linguistic amusement.

Comment: I think linguistic amusement is a very valid reason :)

Comment: It is curious that the Greek word theoremata only seems to exist in Latin texts.  Why would people use a Greek plural when writing Latin?

Comment: Because the Romans held the Greeks in high esteem and emulated them. You would know how many Greek words Cicero uses in his texts for example.

Comment: Maybe the reason why is related to the vowel ending in English?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the other answers, "theorems" is the standard usage in math papers.  In an odd contrast, however, "lemmata" still has some currency as the plural of "lemma" (an intermediate theorem), and crops up pretty regularly even in very recent papers.  On the other hand, my (unresearched) impression is that this too has become less widespread in recent decades.

For comparison, a search for "lemmata" in the text of MathSciNet reviews gives 313 matches, while "theoremata" appears only six times, all in references to the Latin titles of very old papers.

Comment: I see lemmata is even listed in the OED as a possible plural form.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I once wrote "lemmata" in a paper, and the referee commented that "lemmas" is the "21st century plural". (:

Comment: Google ngrams makes a nice picture for lemmata. I would paste it if I could.

Comment: Well, "lemma" retains the Greek suffix in the singular, while "theorem" is anglicized by dropping the suffix. Perhaps the contrast between the plural forms seems less odd with that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted plural seems to be theorems. At least big dictionaries such as Collins or American Heritage Dic. give no other plural form. For some Latin or Greek word Latin and Greek plural-endings can be found but obviously not for all Latin/Greek words. That would be an over-academization of the vocabulary. And I think it is a good thing that foreign plural-endings are restricted to a limited number of words.

Answer (score 0):

For Latin words the Latin plural is sometimes used, possibly because that language has been the lingua franca in science until very recently, which ensures we are familiar, at least in science, with both the singular and plural form in it's Latin original.

In case of Greek or other origins, I guess the plural reflecting the origins of the word would only be used it that plural denotes an individual concept in English, separate from the singular form.

Two examples I can think of are the Greek `stigmata` which is a plural meaning "signs" and the Arabic `Tuareg` (a plural meaning "paths" or "ways").